# Pandas plot change y axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame that looks like this

[image]

I want to plot it:

```
df2[['width', 'height', 'depth']].head(20).plot.bar(figsize=(8, 8), fontsize=16)
```

[image]

Works great, but there I need increase amount of points of Y axis. I want to add numbers like 2400, 1900, etc. How can I do that? Why is there only 6 points on Y axis ?

Comment: can you paste some of the data so that we can try out a few things?

Comment: @ClockSlave https://pastebin.com/3XyxxURV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so you only need to pass in the `yticks` argument. `yticks` is not a direct argument for `bar` but it passed on to `plot`.

```
df2[['width', 'height', 'depth']].head(20).plot.bar(figsize=(8, 8), fontsize=16, yticks = range(0,2600,200))
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

You can also use `xticks` if you want to do the same for the x-axis